# How can i add social login in checkout route of openCart?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, opencart-3, opencart-module

How can i add social login button in checkout in opencart 3+ ?
I am new to openCart and i want to add social login in the checkout so that customers can easily log in from the checkout route.
I searched many websites but i couldn't found any solution for this.

When i edit code in catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/login.twing with my own code

```
  <div class="row login-box">
   <div class="col-sm-6">

   <!--Some default code-->

   <!--My code code-->
    <div class="or-seperator" style="margin:20px 0 10px;text-align: center; border-top: 2px solid #006400;">
     <i style="padding: 0 10px;background: #006400;position: relative; top: -11px;z-index: 1; color:white;">Or login with</i>
    <div>
        <a href="/index.php?route=account/login" style="text-decoration:none;padding:5px 20px"><b>Facebook</b></a>
        <a href="/index.php?route=account/login" style="text-decoration:none"><b>Google</b></a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I could not get any output after adding the above code.

**Help me :-(**

Comment: After you edited files in OC you must refresh modification, clear cache in admin blue gear icon and clear cache in your Journal theme.

Comment: What code should be in control to post new customer? Do you have any idea?